# how to open file in Assets folder in java class

Tags: java, android

i want to use a file which is in Assets folder,but in my application i want to get that file in java but not in Activity class.please help me how can i do this.

I mean to ask is ,i want to write a peice of code for Parsing the json file using Async Task   in java file where my Json files are in Asset folder.

What Class i need to Extend for this and How to Acess the files in Assets.

Thank You

Comment: pass context from the activity and use getAssets() method

Comment: Hopefully this will help 

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-read-file-from-assets/

Comment: if same question asked by any guy then there is atleast 5 or 6 downvotes or comments to paste the code that what have you tried so far possibly flag by users as duplicate or low quality or unclear and after 15 min it is on hold by any moderator but see if a girl ask a same question nobody want acode or any explanation they understand the question by seeing the user name quite funny

Comment: check this http://www.javaexperience.com/how-to-read-file-from-assets-folder-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = assetManager.open("YourFile.txt");
            if ( inputStream != null)
                Log.d(TAG, "It worked!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Do not use

> InputStream is = assetManager.open("assets/YourFile.txt");

Hope this may help you!

Comment: getResources() is not found for java file buddy

Comment: for this have to extends Application class

Answer (score 0):

use this....it helps me, might help u!

```
    AssetManager am = getActivity().getAssets();
```

`OR`

```
    AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();
    try {
        am.open("filename");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the context to that method as an argument and read that file, the string "jsoncontent"  will hold your json content:

```
public class readFile {
public readFile(Context c) throws IOException { 
InputStream stream=c.getAssets().open("yourfile.json");
String jsoncontent;
if(stream!=null){
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    try {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while (reader.readLine() != null) {
            builder.append(reader.readLine());

        }
        jsoncontent = builder.toString();

    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    Log.d("file",jsoncontent);
    }
```

From Your Activity call this:

```
new readFile(getApplicationContext());
```

> EDIT:

If u Want to call it asynchronously (Without blocking the UI thread) call it inside the AsyncTask's doInBackground() method.

The AsyncTask Version of the code is:

```
public class readFile extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Context... context)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        Context mcontext=context[0];
    InputStream stream=mcontext.getAssets().open("yourfilename.json");
    String jsoncontent;
    if(stream!=null){
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        try {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while (reader.readLine() != null) {
                builder.append(reader.readLine());

            }
            jsoncontent = builder.toString();

        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        Log.d("file",jsoncontent);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

in Your activity call:

```
new readFile().execute(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: hi sir, i want to use pure java class only it should not extend any other classes

Comment: So You can use the first one without extending the AsyncTask then call that method inside a AsyncTask in your Activity. @swetha